# C# to F# and Interdependent Functions

Tags: c#, f#, translate, forward-declaration

I would appreciate it if someone kindly helps me with translating this into F#. Not in the class form of course: 1) If I declare ThreadProc first, ThreadProc is supposed to use thread1 and thread2 which are later defined in the main using ThreadProc in the constructors; and if I declare main first, the initialisations will use a function that is not yet defined. 2) If I declare top-level thread1 and thread2 before defining function ThreadProc (e.g., let thread1 = new Thread(fun () -> ())), then that is the version that ThreadProc will ultimately utilise rather than the one later declared in the main.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class Example
{
    static Thread thread1, thread2;

    public static void Main()
    {
        thread1 = new Thread(ThreadProc);
        thread1.Name = "Thread1";
        thread1.Start();

        thread2 = new Thread(ThreadProc);
        thread2.Name = "Thread2";
        thread2.Start();   
    }   

    private static void ThreadProc()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nCurrent thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
        if (Thread.CurrentThread.Name == "Thread1" && 
            thread2.ThreadState != ThreadState.Unstarted)
                thread2.Join();

        Thread.Sleep(4000);
        Console.WriteLine("\nCurrent thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Thread1: {0}", thread1.ThreadState);
        Console.WriteLine("Thread2: {0}\n", thread2.ThreadState);
   }
}
```

Comment: You can translate this to F#, but I don't know what you'll gain by doing that. If you want to do concurrency in F#, there are probably better ways of doing it than by using threads. What is the problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: This was an example in MSDN but as usual, there was no equivalent F# code for it. I wanted to achieve the same functionality in F#.

Comment: BTW, documentation is I think where F# is lacking. You want to look up a functionality or ... in something like C# or MATLAB: there is a neat-and-easy Help System incorporated into the IDE. You'd expect F# with all its big-corporate support would have at least taken care of "good documentation" after 10 years or so, but naah. The integrated help system is non-existent in the case of VS Community Edition.

Comment: Having read though the "Parallel Programming" Chapter of "Beginning F# 4.0", my  understanding is that other that Data Parallelism (parallel arrays and sequences), the rest of the methodologies (e.g., Message Passing, Asynchronous Programming) by-necessity involve some heavy object programming, often to sovle GUI or I/O problems which are non-functional in nature. This makes me wonder what it is exactly that makes functional programming so suitable to "parallelism". From the data science stand point though, I really do appreciate the data parallelism capabilities ... thumbs up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This demonstrates what I was referring to in my comment. It uses ParameterizedThreadStart to pass information to the threads via an F# record.

You are responsible for making sure that the object passed in is of the same type as is expected within the thread proc. The argument to the thread proc is necessarily of type `obj`, so the compiler can't check the type for you. But you can create an appropriately typed shadow of `args` with `let args = args :?> Args` for convenience within the proc.

```
open System
open System.Threading

type Args = { Thread1: Thread; Thread2: Thread }

let threadProc (args: obj) =
    let args = args :?> Args

    printfn "\n\nCurrent Thread: %s" Thread.CurrentThread.Name

    if Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Thread 1" && args.Thread2.ThreadState <> ThreadState.Unstarted then
        args.Thread2.Join ()

    Thread.Sleep(4000)
    Console.WriteLine( "\n\nCurrent thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name )
    Console.WriteLine("Thread 1: {0}", args.Thread1.ThreadState)
    Console.WriteLine("Thread 2: {0}\n", args.Thread2.ThreadState)

let thread1 = new Thread(ParameterizedThreadStart(threadProc))
thread1.Name <- "Thread 1"

let thread2 = new Thread(ParameterizedThreadStart(threadProc))
thread2.Name <- "Thread 2"

let main () =
    let args = { Thread1 = thread1; Thread2 = thread2 }
    thread1.Start(args)
    thread2.Start(args)
    System.Console.ReadKey () |> ignore

do main ()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with the following code. However, I would appreciate any suggestions on making it better, i.e., the smarter/shorter way and/or somehow not-using 'mutable' values:

```
open System
open System.Threading

let mutable thread1 = new Thread( fun () -> () )
let mutable thread2 = new Thread( fun () -> () )

let threadProc () =
    printfn "\n\nCurrent Thread: %s" Thread.CurrentThread.Name

    if ( Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Thread 1" && 
         thread2.ThreadState <> ThreadState.Unstarted ) then 
             thread2.Join ();

    Thread.Sleep(4000)
    Console.WriteLine( "\n\nCurrent thread: {0}", 
                        Thread.CurrentThread.Name )
    Console.WriteLine("Thread 1: {0}", thread1.ThreadState)
    Console.WriteLine("Thread 2: {0}\n", thread2.ThreadState)

thread1 <- new Thread(threadProc)
thread1.Name <- "Thread 1"

thread2 <- new Thread(threadProc)
thread2.Name <- "Thread 2"

let main () = 
    thread1.Start()
    thread2.Start()
    System.Console.ReadKey () |> ignore

do main ()
```

Comment: There are overloads of `new Thread` that allows you to pass in an object to the thread. You can use that to pass in references to the two threads, or anything else for that matter.

Comment: You should only declare thread1 and 2 like this: `let mutable thread1: Thread = null`. The way you do it, you create two extra threads for no reason.

Comment: Thank you: The second one was helpful. I did not get what you meant by the first comment!

Comment: Ok, posted it as an answer. Not meant as the ultimate answer, but just to clarify this particular possiblity.